# Logging IP Addresses for all visitors

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've created my first Elixir/Phoenix app, and I want to log the IP addresses of my visitors.

In my router.ex, I am "logging" the ip addresses for the pages that actually exist.

```
def log_ip(conn, _) do
  conn.remote_ip
  |> Tuple.to_list
  |> Enum.join(".")
  |> IO.puts
  conn
end

...
defmodule Mysite.Router do
  use Mysite.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :log_ip
    ...
  scope "/", Mysite do
    pipe_through :browser
```

This all works fine usually, but I am seeing in the terminal that there are some bots who are trying to access nonexistent pages e.g. "/admin.php", "/command.php". I want to log THESE ip addresses, but the above code is not working for that.

Potentially unrelated, but I also have this code to handle people who hit non-existent links (e.g. /blog/non-existent-page)

```
defimpl Plug.Exception, for: Phoenix.Template.UndefinedError do
  def status(_exception), do: 404
end
```

Is there a way to access the conn and log the remote_ip before I return the 404 (or a better way to handle all of this)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your logger plug in your endpoint rather than your router. The endpoint is in `lib/<yourapp>/endpoint.ex`. You will see something like:

```
  ...
  plug Plug.RequestId
  plug Plug.Logger
  ...
```

You can put both your function definition and the `plug :log_ip` call after those for example.

Comment: Thank you! I created a Module Plug (instead of using a Function Plug) and then added "plug Mysite.Plugs.LogIp" into the endpoint.ex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I achieve based on information above and some digging about logging in Elixir.

1. Created a file `lib/myapp_web/plugs/client_ip_plug.ex`

```erlang
defmodule MyAppWeb.Plugs.ClientIp do
  require Logger
  @behaviour Plug

  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    Logger.metadata(client_ip: get_ip(conn))
    conn
  end

  @doc """
  This code is from Plausible Analytics https://github.com/plausible/analytics/blob/3a1c9e67cd67d5cb1fec68a4dee34f8cd0e056fd/lib/plausible_web/remote_ip.ex
  """
  defp get_ip(conn) do
    forwarded_for = List.first(Plug.Conn.get_req_header(conn, "x-forwarded-for"))

    if forwarded_for do
      String.split(forwarded_for, ",")
      |> Enum.map(&String.trim/1)
      |> List.first()
    else
      to_string(:inet_parse.ntoa(conn.remote_ip))
    end
  end 

end
```

2. Like above I added my Plug between those lines in `endpoint.ex` file

```erlang
  plug Plug.RequestId
  plug MyAppWeb.Plugs.ClientIp
  plug Plug.Logger
```

3. And finally using in logger where I want to log it, for example in `config/release.ex`

```erlang
config :logger, :console,
  level: :info,
  format: "$time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
  metadata: [:request_id, :client_ip]
```